# File Upload/Download Network Root Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, file-upload, server

Using ASP.Net MVC - AdoDB

Im used to upload and download from inside the webserver where I published my files

```
Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/pdfDocuments/");
```

and it worked fine.

But now, I want to send them to another root outside the webserver, inside a network directory(shared folder). Need your help because I already tried this:

```
Server.MapPath(@"\\sharedfolder\UploadedFiles\pdfDocuments\");
```

Please help me on this. Ill appreciate.

Comment: if it's a network share, how about `\\sharedfolder` etc? UNC network paths must start with a double backslash.

Comment: You use the operating systems path, instead of MapPath   i.e. C:\......  Network drives must have a drive letter mapped.  Also, the webserver account the application/page is running as, must have access to the location.

Comment: Already tried with double backslah, and with \\\\ too.

Comment: Network drives must have a drive letter mapped, in my experience.

Comment: Cannot apply a letter like F:\\ because the users might probably using the same letter for another server. Instead, i gave them permissions o' the folder.

Comment: @developer UNC paths (i.e. `\\server\share`) can be used as well, there's no requirement to map a shared folder to a drive letter in order to use it in Windows. I don't know where you got that idea from.

Comment: @rxfeminine it occurs to me that you can just dispense with MapPath entirely in this scenario. Your UNC path (assuming it's correct) is already a fully qualified path. You're no longer trying to map a relative / virtual path into a full path. Since that's all that MapPath does, it no longer has any purpose, you can stop using it.

Comment: @ADyson Used simply this @"\\shared\dir\dir\" it worked while debugging. In pusblishing im receiving other error. Ill will lookup to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you no longer need `Server.MapPath` at all. Its purpose is to map a relative / virtual path (e.g. an incomplete path such as `~/UploadedFiles/pdfDocuments/` into a full path to a file on disk, e.g. that string might get converted into `C:\inetpub\wwwwroot\UploadedFiles\pdfDocuments`, for example.

Since you are now using a UNC path (i.e. a path in the form `\\server\share`), this is already a fully qualified path to a resource. There is no missing information. Therefore in this situation MapPath has no purpose. You can simply remove the line which uses MapPath from your code, and pass your UNC path directly to your upload/download code.

Comment: Used simply this @"\\shared\dir\dir\"

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath only works on relative and virtual paths.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx

If that is a valid path from you server us it directly.